# How to get user domain group?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

How to get name of domain group, that user belong?

I want to compare this in permission class, so ill be able to set same privileges to only specific user.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an article on CodeProject that will show you exactly how to do it:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18102/Howto-Almost-Everything-In-Active-Directory-via-C

I've linked right to the code you will need.  The code (in case the link ever breaks) is as follows:

```
public ArrayList Groups()
{
    ArrayList groups = new ArrayList();
    foreach (System.Security.Principal.IdentityReference group in
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.LogonUserIdentity.Groups)
    {
        groups.Add(group.Translate(typeof
            (System.Security.Principal.NTAccount)).ToString());
    }
    return groups;
}
```